# How to change name of devices in packet tracer

Tags: networking, naming, hostname

How do I rename devices in packet tracer instead of them saying laptop0 laptop1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the device, then click on the name of it, and now you can change it.
Or double-click on the device, then config tab, then Display name tab.

[image: Like this image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I know of that can allow you to make the change.

1. You can double click on the tag "laptop0" and change it from  the text box
2. Double click on the laptop icon > Config > Global Settings > Display Name